# Is desert usually a place where lots of paap/adharm has happened?

Tags: sin, earth

In Hinduism, is this a thing ? In many texts I’m trying to read, this seem to be implied. Not sure though. That desert type region occurs where tons of sins have taken place ?

Because desert can’t support life the way a forests and rivers, lakes, can support people, animals, etc

However this might be too much sweeping generalization.

Also would this mean that Satyug has entire earth covered in green big forests, while Kaliyug is many deserts.

Comment: Another question on here said that 10,000 yrs ago, Middle East was very green and forested. Then lots of bad bad stuff, and now is all dry desert. Parts of India are also large deserts, of course, other countries too.

Comment: Not necessarily. Whole Ramayana era paap happened in Sri Lanka and there isn't nothing sort of any thing there, except water around.

Comment: @User29449 Thanks !